# Save file using table variable and date

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have code to archive a version of the document - renaming the file using a value stored in a table within the Word document, followed by today's date. I have the date aspect working - but cannot get the value in say table 1, row 1, cell 2 into the SaveAs statement.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call DocArchive()
End Sub

Sub DocArchive()
ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:="Plan archive " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Call DocArchive() 
End Sub

Sub DocArchive() 
' You need to chop off two characters at the end of the cell (a chr(13)
' and a chr(7). You may need to do more...
ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:="Plan archive " _
 & left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Text, _
   len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Text)-2)) _
 & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") 
End Sub
```